# Composite Template with 2 Documents: Want Multiple Receipients to only receive one of them

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using a composite template to send a group of 3 documents.   Only one of them needs two signatures.   The 'second' receipient is still getting all 3 documents (but is only required to sign the correct one).   Is there a way that the 'second' recipient ONLY receives the document she signs and does not see the other two?

```
{
  "compositeTemplates": [
    {
      "compositetemplateid": "1",
      "document": {
        "assignTabsToRecipientId": "1",
        "documentBase64": "hyZWYNCjI1NDE1MQ0KJSVFT0YNCg==",
        "documentId": "1234",
        "fileExtension": "pdf",
        "name": "Sample App # 1",
        "transformPdfFields": "true"
      },
      "inlineTemplates": [
        {
          "recipients": {
            "signers": [
              {
                "email": "tom@tom.com",
                "name": "Tom Scout",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "routingOrder": "1",
                "tabs": {
                  "datesignedtabs": [
                    {
                      "tabLabel": "DocuSignDateSigned"
                    }
                  ],
                  "signHereTabs": [
                    {
                      "tabLabel": "DocuSignSignHere"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "email": "susan@gmail.com",
                "name": "Susan Scout",
                "recipientId": "2",
                "routingOrder": "1",
                "tabs": {
                  "datesignedtabs": [
                    {
                      "tabLabel": "DocuSignDateSigned_SP"
                    }
                  ],
                  "signHereTabs": [
                    {
                      "tabLabel": "DocuSignSignHere_SP"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "sequence": "1"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "compositetemplateid": "2",
      "document": {
        "assignTabsToRecipientId": "1",
        "documentBase64": "adsfadsfK",
        "documentId": "1235",
        "fileExtension": "pdf",
        "name": "Sample App # 2",
        "transformPdfFields": "true"
      },
      "inlineTemplates": [
        {
          "recipients": {
            "signers": [
              {
                "email": "tom@tom.com",
                "name": "Tom Scout",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "routingOrder": "1",
                "tabs": {
                  "datesignedtabs": [
                    {
                      "tabLabel": "DocuSignDateSigned"
                    }
                  ],
                  "signHereTabs": [
                    {
                      "tabLabel": "DocuSignSignHere"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "sequence": "1"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "compositetemplateid": "3",
      "document": {
        "assignTabsToRecipientId": "1",
        "documentBase64": "JVBERi0xLj",
        "documentId": "1236",
        "fileExtension": "pdf",
        "name": "Sample App # 3",
        "transformPdfFields": "true"
      },
      "inlineTemplates": [
        {
          "recipients": {
            "signers": [
              {
                "email": "tom@tom.com",
                "name": "Tom Scout",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "routingOrder": "1",
                "tabs": {
                  "datesignedtabs": [
                    {
                      "tabLabel": "DocuSignDateSigned"
                    }
                  ],
                  "signHereTabs": [
                    {
                      "tabLabel": "DocuSignSignHere"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "sequence": "1"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "emailSubject": "Testing Platform PDF Fields",
  "status": "sent"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify **excludedDocuments** as an array for a recipient inside the inlineTemplates as per the documentation below.

> Specifies the documents that are not visible to this recipient.
> Document Visibility must be enabled for the account and the
> `enforceSignerVisibility` property must be set to true for the envelope
> to use this.

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/create/#schema__envelopedefinition_compositetemplates_inlinetemplates_recipients_signers_excludeddocuments

Comment: Thanks!   I had tried 'exclude..." but I was not using the 'enforceSignerVisibility' property.  Now it works great!

Answer (score 0):

Also checkout the [Document Visibility](https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&rsc_301&bundleId=gbo1643332197980&topicId=eui1578456411411.html&_LANG=enus) feature.

In summary: Document Visibility only shows documents to a signer if that document has a tab (field) on it for the signer.